# How to find out if scheduled sql job did not run

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following scenario:
In SQL Server Agent, there is a scheduled job that runs everyday at 6 AM and it works fine everyday. One day the server fails at 5 AM til 8 AM, but when the server is up again is 2 hours later than when the job that was scheduled to run.

How can I check that the job should have had run previously and indicate some kind of "Missed Schedule" status?

Approach:
Run `EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_GET_COMPOSITE_JOB_INFO  @job_id` and check that `last_run_time` & `last_run_time` exists in `[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory]`, if it doesn't exist it means that job was scheduled but it did not run. Is this approach correct?

Any suggestions/comments?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want code to check the status? If not, I would start with right click the job and 'view history'

Comment: Can you add some notification into your job? When job completes successfully you may notify by some means. If notification is not received in time so there is some problem with job.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to figure this seemingly - had to already be solved problem - out.  Seems like it isn't as common a need as one might think.  Anyhow, I was about to embark on the journey of writing my own check when I found the below.  It seems to work, in that it caught the job I wanted it to find on my server.

The issue with your approach is that if it is a fairly quickly recurring job or it runs every day but skipped Saturday and you check on Monday.  It seemed to me to do this right, you needed to get into the frequency and build a table of when it ought to have run then go check history and see if it ran.  The below is long and will take time to understand but it does seem to be doing that.

http://www.nuronconsulting.com/TemplateScripts_SQL_Agent_JobsJobScript_FindMissedJobs_sql.aspx